# SSIS Creating a new folder depending upon configuration

Tags: ssis

I have to create a new folder every time my SSIS package is run. 
I was able to do that using a new connection with `ConnectionManagerType = FILE` and `ConnectionString = C:\Test`. 
I am using this connection string with a `file system task` that checks if the folder is already there then it will do nothing else it will create a `new` folder. 
Every thing is running fine till here. 
The issue is that now I need to create a new folder depending on the configuration selected while running the package

say if UAT is selected 
[image]
then the folder name should be `c:\Test_UAT`, for configuration type =`Development` the folder name should be `c:\Test_Development`

Please help me achieving this. 
and please be a little specific since I m very new to SSIS

Answer (score 2):

U need to define the `expression` for the `File connection Manager`

1.Create a variable `Configuration` of data type `String`

2.Right Click on the `File Connection Manager` which you have created and select `Properties`

3.Click the expression and in the dialogue box select the `connection string`  property

[image]

[image]

4.Click the expression and write the folder location

[image]

5.The File System Task will have the following configuration.In the source connection select the File connection manager which you have created

[image]

If you change the Configuration value to `Test` or `Development` ,appropriate folders will be created in the location specified above

```
Updated :
```

To add the variable in the configuration Just click on `SSIS Package Configuration` .Edit your configuration file .Select the variable and click the value checkbox

Once the configuration is done ,you can the change the value in the `xml config file` and that will get reflected in `SSIS` during `runtime`
[image]

Comment: Thanks mate.. it helped much.. but major part is still missing.. the main issue is that I need the Configuration mapped to the Configuration settings of the project. e.g I have set the value of configuration settings to UAT the variable should be updated automatically to test_UAT

Comment: I guess there is a little missunderstanding...I have updated the question.. please have a look at the new image inserted.. that is the configuration settings that I need to create folder name upon..

Comment: R u planning to run your package from BIDS ? If not then how do you plan to change  different environment at runtime ?